# How to get Column Names using Hibernate ScrollableResults?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc, resultset, scrollableresults

I have below code, which works fine. But i need to get the column Headers.
Is there any way to get ResultSet reference from ScrollableResults? I noticed that AbstractScrollableResults has ResultSet, but i cannot get handle to it.

```
           List<String> lists = new ArrayList<>() ;
           try (ScrollableResults r = statelessSession
                    .createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM TBL** where id=?")
                    .setParameter("id", id).
                    .setReadOnly(true)
                    .setFetchSize(FETCH_SIZE)
                    .setCacheable(false)
                    .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY)) {

                while (r.next()) {
                    String result = Arrays.asList(r.get()).toString();
                    lists.add(result);
                }
}
```

Anyone knows how to get column headers?
Thanks in Advance.